# Two unresolved resourses

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am new to coding and I am working with the google developer code instructions, I have copied the code letter-for-letter but in one section of the code a lot of issues are arising, Android Studio is telling me there are unresolved references (for the (R.raw.placesjson) and (PlaceResponse in two places). I am using android studio and the language I am using is Kotlin. Any help on the matter will be very much appreciated. My code is as follows

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    class PlacesReader(private val context: MainActivity) {

        private val gson = Gson()

        private val inputStream: InputStream
            get() = context.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.placesjson)


        fun read(): List<Place> {
            val itemType = object : TypeToken<List<PlaceResponse>>() {}.type
            val reader = InputStreamReader(inputStream)
            return gson.fromJson<List<PlaceResponse>>(reader, itemType).map {
                it.toPlace()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `R.somethingoranother` usually refers to some resources defined elsewhere in your project (i.e. non-code stuff like entries in XML files and/or files on some folders). Are you sure that you followed **all** the instructions in the tutorial and didn't just copy the code?

Comment: Check in your project `raw` package  and `PlaceResponse` data class is present. If not present then need to add.

Comment: I just tried to create a data class, and found that I had one already, have I missed something in my data class that causing the issue. My data class is:     data class Place(
        val name:String,
        val LatLng:LatLng,
        val address: String,
        val rating: Float
    )

Answer (score 0):

Just create 'raw' folder inside 'res' folder and place placesjson file inside that raw folder. Then you will be able to access that placesjson file through your program like R.raw. placesjson

Comment: Thanks this worked, there is no longer an "unresolved reference messages on the raw

Comment: I just tried to create a data class, and found that I had one already, have I missed something in my data class that causing the issue. My data class is: data class Place( val name:String, val LatLng:LatLng, val address: String, val rating: Float ). Do you know what I could have missed thats preventing my placereponse connecting to my dataclass.